# Launching a website from a C# class library

Tags: c#

I have an asp.net core application which references a class library.

A method in a class library is called on a button click on asp.net core application and the method in class library has to launch a website. I got below single line of code from google, but does not seem to be working -

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");

Can anyone help me, how can I launch a website using C# code?

Thanks

Comment: by "launch a website" you mean "open new browser (chrome, firefox, ie) window and navigate to some web resource"?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com");` you can't using `asp.net` that way. You can open a new site by adding `window.open('http://www.google.com', 'Google');` in a buttons `OnClientClick`... Another option is to use redirects in code behind.

Comment: If we really are talking about an ASP.NET web application, it is not possible to start a browser on the end user's machine from a class library. That would be an insane security violation. If you need the end user to access a third party site, you can [redirect](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/2cde4c7c-b43d-4c67-acc2-614ae9b0fcf5.aspx) them. However it is doubtful you'll be able to do that from a class library. You would need the ASP.NET application itself to return a redirect header.

Comment: What is your application Desktop or Web App?

Comment: with all the above comments, I assume that it is not possible to launch a site like that. @tontonsevilla its a web application which has to launch a site but class library has to put a check and decide if allowed to launch or not. There are other ways to achieve like class library can return true or false and then client can redirect. But I wanted to do it under the hood so that client(consumer of class library) is unaware of the checks and with all these changes client still relies on the same interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is a web application. You can return your desired url to open in the controller action from your class library method.
Example:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
    string urlToRedirect = yourClassObj.GetUrl();
    return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```